# Unaccepted Answers

Tags: discussion

Suppose a user just visits this site once just for the sake of posing a question, and never visits the site again then will the answer never be accepted? What to do with such unaccepted answers.

Comment: Nothing?.......

Comment: This annoys me too. Some posters seem to think that an upvote is sufficient to accept an answer. Others just add a thank-you comment. How can we motivate/educate people to accept answers? Questions with unaccepted answers leave the bad impression that no answer was correct or truly informative.

Comment: Perhaps users with enough reputation should be allowed to mark a particular question as being answered after a certain period (2 weeks?) of inactivity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The information will still be there for any other internet travellers to benefit from -- assuming the question is on topic and considered interesting to the community enough to answer.

It will also permanently be a part of our creative commons data dumps, so it can be used and remixed (with proper attribution) by the wider internet as well.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the robot keeps bringing them back.  I would like to see that stop, either entirely or after one or two tries.  Maybe add a vote to close type thing that doesn't close the question, just stops it from coming back.

Comment: [The bot only bumps questions that have no upvoted answers.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) So once someone posts an answer and it gets voted up, the question will stop coming back.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  So if we don't see a reasonable answer we should vote to close as not a question or something.  Or just randomly upvote an answer

Comment: Or let the question keep coming back—if it's a worthwhile question and has not generated an upvotable answer, it deserves occasional re-exposure, as there should be a continual stream of new users to see it for the first time.